# iOS Updating Property of an Object

Tags: objective-c, object

I'm new to iOS dev and a question that I'd appreciate some guidance on.

I have a ViewController which has a property that I want to regularly replace:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
```

Now in another class where I update that property, I first alloc and init the ViewController  then update that property accordingly. However when I come to replace that image with another it only ever uses the first image. If however I instantiate another ViewController with alloc init it all works ok.

So my question is that the correct/best practice way to update, by creating new instances of my ViewController - memory efficiency wise is it best practice?

Thanks.

Comment: check the existence of viewcontroller as if (viewController) viewController = nil; then allocate it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you definitely want to change the image, rather than replacing the entire view controller.

Can you show the code where you are changing the image? Also, please specify if you want to change the *image **view*** or the *image* inside it. (The image view is what displays the actual image on the screen. I suggest you name your property `imageView`, to avoid confusion.)

Here are two examples. I'm assuming there is a variable 'theViewController' that holds a reference your view controller.

Replacing the image view:

```
// Create a new image view with a new image inside it
theViewController.image = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img1"]];
```

Replacing the image:

```
// Put a new image into the existing image view
theViewController.image.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"img1"];
```

The last example demonstrates why the property name `imageView` is preferably to `image`: now, it looks like you are changing 'the image on an image'. But actually, you are changing the image on an imageView.